# cakephp 4 - authentication 2 - How to display message when not identified

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I use authentication (2) plugin with cakephp4. 
I have set :

```
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/users/login',
```

in order to redirect requests that need authentication. It works fine.

But I'd like to add a message, a flash message for example, that would say "You must be log in to acceess this page".

Is there an easy way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific functionality for that yet: **https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/issues/316**

It could be solved in many different ways, personally I have done this before by catching `Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthenticatedException` in an extended authentication component, by overwriting `\Authentication\Controller\Component\AuthenticationComponent::doIdentityCheck()`:

```php
<?php
// src/Controller/Component/AppAuthenticationComponent.php

/*
load in `AppController::initialize()` via:

$this->loadComponent('Authentication', [
    'className' => \App\Controller\Component\AppAuthenticationComponent::class,
]);
*/

namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthenticatedException;
use Authentication\Controller\Component\AuthenticationComponent;
use Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent;

/**
 * @property FlashComponent $Flash
 */
class AppAuthenticationComponent extends AuthenticationComponent
{
    public $components = [
        'Flash'
    ];

    protected function doIdentityCheck(): void
    {
        try {
            parent::doIdentityCheck();
        } catch (UnauthenticatedException $exception) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('You must be logged in to access this page.'));

            throw $exception;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do it manually in your app controller, for that you'd have to disable the plugin component's automatic identity check, and do that check on your own:

```php
// src/Controller/AppController.php

public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication', [
        'requireIdentity' => false
    ]);
}

public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);

    $action = $this->request->getParam('action');
    if (
        !in_array($action, $this->Authentication->getUnauthenticatedActions(), true) &&
        !$this->Authentication->getIdentity()
    ) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('You must be logged in to access this page.'));

        throw new UnauthenticatedException('No identity found.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ndm,
I've tried the first solution but I have this exception :
`No identity found. You can skip this check by configuring
 requireIdentity to be false`

In AppController.php I have the 2 lines:
`$this->loadComponent('Authentication.Authentication');
$this->loadComponent('AppAuthentication');`

Is it correct ? I guess I have missed something

Comment: @dype Not quite correct, you need to stop using the original plugins authentication component, and only load `AppAuthentication`!

Comment: I've tried that, but then I have some errors : `Call to a member function allowUnauthenticated() on null`. But I found why : I have to change everywhere in my code : `$this->Authentication-> by `$this->AppAuthentication->` correct ?

Comment: @dype Correct, but you could also use aliasing to use the original name, then you don't need to change anything else, I've updated the code example to show that.

Comment: ok thanks @npm, thank you for the cake lesson ;-)
A small mistake in the alias :
className' => \App\Controller\Component\AppAuthentication**Component**::class,

Comment: @AngelS.Moreno Not using plugin notation was intentional, as the goal of that `loadComponent()` call is to create an alias with a specific class defined via the `className` Option, the call is _not_ meant to load the plugin's component! Using plugin notation in such a case can lead to undesired internal behavior, as the dot notated name would be used for duplicate checks and the like, unlike when not not using the `className` option, resulting in possible clashes to not be detected.